# how to update yum in centos 7?

Tags: centos, updates, yum

Error message when run yum on Centos 7

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
To enable Red Hat Subscription Management repositories:
   subscription-manager repos --enable <repo>
To enable custom repositories:
   yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

Comment: »»To enable Red Hat Subscription Management ..«« indicates a RHEL 7 OS, not CentOS 7. ..... Repo example, CentOS 7 https://www.dropbox.com/s/dief7mp7i2t43gu/CentOS7-repo-ex.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: You should try asking over on [su] as this place is for *programming* related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your post indicates that you are using CentOS 7 but your code snippet implies you are actually using Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

RHEL does not ship with any usable package repositories by default. You don't need to *update* yum, you need to enable a software repository so you can use yum to download packages from it.

The proper way to resolve this is to either [purchase](https://www.redhat.com/en/store/linux-platforms) a RHEL Subscription License to their Enterprise Software Repositories or sign up for a [developer license](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/03/31/no-cost-rhel-developer-subscription-now-available/), which is free with some small restrictions.

Alternatively, you can use [this process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433046/how-do-i-enable-centos-repositories-on-rhel-red-hat) to add the CentOS 7 repositories to RHEL 7. Which will allow you to get by for the most part.